# Java Draw All Glyphs of a Font

Tags: java, fonts

### Question:

Given a Font object, how do I draw *all* the glyphs/symbols/characters of the Font?

### I know the following:

I know how to create a Font object from file.

I know to use g.setFont(...) ; // g is a Graphics2D

I know to use g.drawString(...); // g is a Graphics2D

However, I don't want to draw just the A-Z, a-z, 0-9 characters. I want to draw all the glyphs of the font. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question: how do I determine all the code points a font implements?

Comment: I don't know much about fonts. Is a code point = a single glyph, or "character" ?

Comment: It's a character.  What's the reason for doing this? Are you restricting yourself to English language fonts? Or does this include Asian fonts as well (this is why I asked about code points).

Comment: I'm not limiting myself to English fonts. For fun, I'm trying to write a simple program that just shows all the characters of a font.

Comment: @user1311390: note that a single glyph can represent multiple characters *and even multiple codepoints*! For example many fonts include a single glyph for "ff" or "fi" (called ligatures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
final Font f = new Font(...);

for (char c = 0x0000; c <= Character.MAX_VALUE; c++) {
    if (f.canDisplay(c)) {
        // draw it ...
    }
}
```

See [`Font.canDisplay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29)

> **`public boolean canDisplay(int codePoint)`**
>
> Checks if this Font has a glyph for the specified character.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `codePoint` - the character (Unicode code point) for which a glyph is needed.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if this `Font` has a glyph for the character; `false` otherwise.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `IllegalArgumentException` - if the code point is not a valid Unicode code point.
>
> **Since:**
>
> ```
>    1.5
> ```
>
> **See Also:**
>
> [`Character.isValidCodePoint(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint%28int%29)

Comment: Note that drawing all codepoints that the font can display does **not** necessarily mean that all glyphs of the font are displayed! For example ligatures (for example for "ff" or "fi") will probably *not* be rendered by this single-codepoint approach.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: sounds reasonable - out of my depth at that point.

Comment: Mine, too; see also [*Understanding characters, keystrokes, codepoints and glyphs*](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter02). Empirically, `canDisplay()` isn't perfectly reliable.

Comment: @trashgod: that's a very complete and very good resource, thanks!

Comment: Your code is an infinite loop. When `c == 0xFFFF` then `c++` sets it back to `0`.

Comment: @Nateowami char is like int, and int can go to 0xffffffff so, after 0xffff, it will be 0x00010000 and it still has room up to 0xFF.FF.FF.FF

Comment: @Salivan `char` works somewhat like `int`, but their max values differ [`Integer.MAX_VALUE != Character.MAX_VALUE` and `0xFFFF == Character.MAX_VALUE`](https://ideone.com/nekcST). Try running the code and you'll see it's infinite: https://ideone.com/SMwSb3

Comment: Wow, thank you for clarification, yes that is true.

**public static final char MAX_VALUE = 65535**

Comment: This solution only iterates over code points in the Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane). The highest valid Unicode code point is U+10FFFF, so you'll have to expand the loop's range (and use an int), and handle the higher code points properly in your code (e.g. process surrogate pairs) if necessary.